# Getting this error while launching a Jetty app "Launching application_name". 'java.lang.String org.eclipse.m2e.core.embedder.ArtifactKey.groupId()"

Tags: java, eclipse, server, m2eclipse

This is the output log for the error that i'm getting on the console.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching application-name".
org.eclipse.m2e.core.embedder.ArtifactKey.groupId()Ljava/lang/String;
```

I'm on java 8 and maven 3.6.3. Is it related any of the system configuration?

Comment: It is probably related to the Eclipse version (or to be more precise to the m2e version, the Maven support of Eclipse) and probably also to the additional plugins you installed. Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: @howlger changing the eclipse version worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to the Eclipse version, more specifically the [m2e](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core) version, the Maven support of Eclipse, and also to the additional plugins you have installed that do not seem to work with the m2e version you have. [Maybe due to the multiple API breakages in m2e 2.x](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#multiple-api-breakage).

Update the affected plugin that uses m2e (if you don't know which plugin, go to the *Error Log* view and look in the stack trace to see what m2e is calling). If no newer version of the plugin is yet available, using an older Eclipse/m2e version might work as a temporary workaround (m2e 2.x has been introduced in Eclipse 2022-09).